# exec in comand line after a pip install on windows

Tags: python, windows, pip

Hy,
I'm on windows, and a python beginner.
I do a

```
 pip install someInternalTool
```

in order to install some internal tool .

issue is, when I do

```
cmd> someInternalTool
```

I have the message "someInternalTool is not recognized as an internal or external command"

I know that If I did it on linux, it would be supposed to launch this tool, but it don't seem to work on windows.

Any idea how I can make it run?
I see the package is in
C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages

Comment: Is ```someInternalTool``` supposed to be a binary?  Is that site-packages in the path?  I'm assuming ```cmd>``` is your commandline prompt?

Comment: That should work if installation happened correctly, and if the tool installs itself as an executable. Just to be sure it's not an issue with mixed environments, do `where pip` and `where python` report pip and python coming from the same environment?

Comment: What python IDE do you use?